# Delphi 2006 - 3 camadas - TSocketConnection - TClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

Tenho uma aplicação rodando em 3 camadas.

Quando a camada client não encontra o server ou por outro motivo qualquer, de forma correta, me estoura um erro em tela, estou usando TSocketConnections e TClientDataSets.

Precisava apenas tratar ou mesmo mascarar estes erros informados do TSocketConnection, ou seja, o que preciso é que mesmo que ocorra algum erro que a mensagem não seja apresentada em tela, atualmente o aplicativo do lado client já esta preparado para prosseguir após o erro, mas como é apresentado o erro e este pede a iteração (clique no OK), a parte client não consegue prosseguir.

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Pode colocar na pergunta o código com problema?

Comment: Cigano, obrigado pelo interesse. Mas na verdade não existe um código com problema ... o que preciso é usar algo que não traga o erro em tela, já tentei TRY-EXCEPT mas não funciona, já tentei também tratar através da Exceção dentro do TRY-EXCEPT, mas também não funcionou, o que me parece é que pela aplicação client, sempre que houver um erro de conexão na aplicação servidor envolvendo o TSockettconnection será apresentado o erro em tela.

Comment: Quando o cliente faz a requisição no servidor, sempre é bom testar a conexão antes, mas se houver uma conexão e der um problema no servidor, tem como tratar uma mensagem e está mensagem voltar para o cliente com o erro tratado, você deve declarar no parâmetro da função que é requisitada out sMensagem: String, assim o cliente quando requisita o servidor ele espera o retorno.

Comment: Jefferson, obrigado. Quando eu vou iniciar o processo, que é longo, eu verifico a conexão, e aborto caso não haja conexão ... o meu problema é quando esta conexão cai durante o processo, pois, o TSocketConnection apresenta o erro e fica esperando o OK, já tratei a parte client para prosseguir, mas estou esbarrando em ter que dar este ok, precisava era que mesmo dando erro, nada fosse apresentado em tela e desta forma a parte client pudesse seguir normalmente (como os tratamentos que já são feitos), tudo que fiz até o momento não conseguiu impedir de apresentar seu erro.

Answer (score 1):

Se a ideia é recolher os erros de Socket silenciosamente, eu usaria o [Log4Delphi](http://log4delphi.sourceforge.net/).

Se a ideia é pegar a nível de aplicação, existem ferramentas pagas como [EurekaLog](https://www.eurekalog.com/) e [MadException](http://www.madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm) que faz isso por você.

Ou, se preferir, pode usar o recurso `JclDebug` da [biblioteca Jedi](https://pilif.github.io/2002/12/jcldebug/), que é livre.

Comment: Valeu Cigano, vou dar uma olhada neste Log4Delphi ... a ideia é mesmo pegar silenciosamente os erros, e não deixar a parte client estacionada aguardando um OK quando um erro deste aparece.